# How to generate unique squence numbers using Oracle 11g?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

My requirement is to get assign a number to bunch of records. That means, I will assign one unique number to multiple records to recognise I have processed many records under one number. 
Now, I wanted to get the unique number from Oracle 11g table and then assign multiple records and store into another Oracle table.

The idea is to fetch the unique number in Java screen from Oracle table. So, front end Java backend Oracle 11g.

Can any one help me how to get the unique sequence number by using Oracle 11g table?

Comment: Use a [sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571)

Comment: Do the records already exist in your table, or is the intention to assign unique numbers as new rows are added?

Comment: Dear Bob, The proposal is to assign number(Ex: 1) to multiple records fetched received from another application. That means, 1 should be assigned to all records fetched.

Comment: And how are these records supposed to be received from another application?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate a uniq number to a set of records you can use a oracle sequence same as this:

```
create sequence seq_dest_table
minvalue 1
maxvalue 9999999999999; -- only one time you create a sequence 

grp_id:=seq_dest_table.nextval;

insert into dest_table (grp_id,col1,col2,col3,...)
values (grp_id,col1v1,col2v1,col3v1,... )

insert into dest_table (grp_id,col1,col2,col3,...)
values (grp_id,col1v2,col2v2,col3v2,... )
```

Sequences are uniq but you may have order problem in clustering and you can use **order** option in the sequence but it may affected performance!